# How to check if an object of one list contains any object of another list

Tags: java, list

We have two lists one is of type Question and the other of type Tag.

The Question class has those attributes

```
private String id;
private String header;
private String content;
private List<Tag> tags;
private Long timeStamp;
```

The Question list has all questions in it and the Tag list has all tags in it. We wanna check if One question contains any tag of the tag list. I want to do this for all questions.

With question.getTags, I get the list of tags.

The Tag class has an attribute called counter.

I will give some pseudocode to actually show you what I wanna do

```
List<Tag> allTags = ...
List<Question> allQuestions = ...
Map<Tag,Integer> map = new Hashmap<>();

if(one question contains any tag of allTags) {
     tag.setCounter(counter+1);
     map.put(tag,tag.getCounter);
}
```

In the end I wanna have a map where the key is the tag and the value the counter of that tag.

How can I actually do this?

EDIT here is my Tag.java

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Document(collection = "tag")
public class Tag {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Long timeStamp;

public Tag(String name) {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.name = name;
        this.timeStamp = Instant.now().getEpochSecond()*1000;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Tag tag = (Tag) o;
        return Objects.equals(getId(), tag.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, I misswrote that, thanks

Comment: Note that `@Data` already implies `@Getter` and `@Setter`, so those two could be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a counter attribute in the `Tag` class to count how often a `Tag` occurs in a list of `questions` is a design error. You don't need such a counter there.

A possibly plausible example: Imagine you have a class `Student` and a class `Course`. To keep track of how many students are in a course, there is no need for a counter in the `Student` class. In the same way a class `Tag` should only contain the attributes of a tag. That said, you can achieve your goal without the counter with either one of the two following approachs (provided you have java 8 or higher and your `Tag` class overrides the `equals` and `hashcode` methods):

Approach 1 using `Streams` & `Collectors.groupingBy`

```
Map<Tag,Long> map = allQuestions.stream()
            .flatMap(q -> q.getTags().stream())
            .filter(allTags::contains)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()));
```

Approach 2 using `List.forEach` & `Map.compute`

```
Map<Tag, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    allQuestions.forEach(q -> {
        q.getTags()
                .stream()
                .filter(allTags::contains)
                .forEach(t -> map2.compute(t, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1));
    });
```

Or using a traditional `for-loop` and `if-else` block

```
Map<Tag, Integer> map3 = new HashMap<>();

for (Question q : allQuestions) {
    for (Tag t : q.getTags()) {
        if (allTags.contains(t)) {
            if (map3.containsKey(t)) {
                map3.put(t, map3.get(t) + 1);
            } else {
                map3.put(t, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I Edited my tag class into the question, I tried all of your solutions niether gave me all the right values,some tags are missing, some counter values are wrong, is ist because the implementations of my equals and hashCode are wrong?

Comment: OK I think I got it to work, changed the implementation of my hashCode method

Comment: @YasinEraslan Freut mich, dass es läuft. Grüße.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work perfectly

```
    int count=0; 
    for(Question q : allQuestions){
     for(Tag t : q.getTags()){
     if(allTags.contains(t)){ 
        count=map.containsKey(t) ? map.get(t)+1 : 0;
        map.put(t,count);
       }
     }
    }
```

Comment: I think you meant `map.get(t) + 1` instead of `map.get(t)++`. Also, there's no need to declare and initialize count outside the loops

Comment: Thank you I edited it, I prefere declaring my variables outside the loops is it a bad habit?

Comment: I tried this approach too, same result as the solution on the bottom, I guess the implementation of my hashCode and equals is not quite right